# Why do these ImageButtons changing position using relative layout?

Tags: android, xml

Learning some Android development through trial and error, however I'm having a slight issue with the rendering of buttons on top of an image view depending on the resolution of the phone.

I have an imageview with two imagebuttons (at the moment) on top.  They are relative to the imageview.  I will post the xml markup below.  The issue is when I run this on the "Nexus 4" in Android studio, everything looks correct.  When I debug through my Samsung Galaxy S4, the imagebuttons are off slightly, and I'm not sure why this would be a problem if everything is truly relative to the imageview. I understand that the resolutions are different, but how would one go about making sure that this renders the same on the smallest of screens, as well as the newer 1080p screens that are becoming more popular?

I can post pictures if need be, but I feel that the xml will provide adequate information on the issue.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/SRMap"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:background="@drawable/sr_map"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:contentDescription="Map of Summoners Rift"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="177dp"/>

<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/BlueSideAlert_BlueBuff"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_alert_circle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SRMap"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SRMap"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"/>

<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/BlueSideAlert_RedBuff"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_alert_circle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SRMap"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SRMap"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"/>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the imagebuttons are off slightly"

Comment: Like the rendered image on the nexus 4 emulator is spot on, but when i use my phone to debug, the imagebuttons go off maybe 10dp right and 10 dp down.  So they look "off", sorry for not being explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled this in a fairly ugly way, but it works across all screen sizes now.  Basically say the primary image was 800x800 dp (the image view).  The buttons would be smaller than this (20x20 dp), however through transparency, i created 800x800 dp imageviews (note: no longer buttons) with everything transparent but the "icon" (still 20x20 dp).  Although slightly larger in terms of file size, it's negligible in my case.  Now no matter what the size of the screen, the imageviews all stretch the same amount, thus removing any guesswork from using the different pixel densities.

I realize that this wasn't the most graceful solution, but I cannot see any drawback aside from making some of the layout development more difficult, and the image files are slightly larger.  I used Paint.NET in order to create the .png's that I used.

I am creating an app that is relevant to me, and that I figured would be easy to implement using some of the core functionality already provided in android.  My idea is a simple League of Legends Jungle Timer Application.  This is important to know as I link the pictures so people can understand the context.

Note that both images are the same resolution, there is just no border on the second one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad3LZ.jpg 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfhRM.png

Additional details:
  For this app I have disabled the "landscape" orientation, I plan on doing this using some of the details that were provided on this page (layouts).

All of these icon ImageViews are relative to the map, which is the first link, so they will always resize correctly.  There are 12 of them also, if it matters.

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> but how would one go about making sure that this renders the same on the smallest of screens, as well as the newer 1080p screens that are becoming more popular?

[See the Docs here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) about supporting different screen sizes/resolutions. You create separate `layout` files adjusted to what you need. Simply use different qualifiers for the layout folder name according to the docs and the correct one will be used according to the device that loads it.

You can try and adjust one file to work on different screens but you are a lot better off using different layouts if it will be ran on different screen sizes and resolutions.

For example: you can have a default `res/layout` folder and a `res/layout-large` to be used on larger screens

Comment: I understand that much, i could create a new layout for each screen there is, but I was just hoping there would be a graceful solution to allow this app to look the same relative to the screen size.  Not sure it's possible, just changed my emulator to a 2.3" screen... looks even worse in terms of offset, but that is to be expected.

Comment: If you want it to look as nice as possible on different screens then that's the best way

Comment: @codeMagic I don't fully agree. Coomanperson918's problem is better solved by adjusting the position of layout elements through code(after the view is drawn). This would work on all screen sizes. `res/layout-large` can be used to utilize the extra space. Use it to get creative with the view(may be change that sliding drawer to fixed). Positioning with absolute values will always(?) have issues: looking great on one device, looking odd on another.

Comment: @vikram I understand your point but I still think its more easily handled with different files plus it will be easier to adjust for different resolutions and not just sizes